# Restrict deployments to app(play) stores in Fastlane?

Tags: continuous-deployment, fastlane

With Fastlane, what options exist to restrict triggering the release lane and thus deploying to the app/play store? Is restricting who can approve a merge into the branch the only control?

Answer (score 0):

You can set [`skip_upload_apk`](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/upload_to_play_store/) for Android or [`skip_binary_upload`](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/deliver/) for iOS to avoid deploying to the stores.